# Google cannot find me

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle, algebra

> Google cannot find me,
>   reflected I'm lemon and lime,
>   googling 'me' is when you fall,
>   me and meme will answer all.

What am I?

Line 1 hint: Posted I still

> have no matches in Google.

Line 2 hint: Take my reflection

> as vertical, a fairy's competitor.

Line 3 hint: Fall here means your

> final one, clued by the distance.

Line 4 hint: This confirms the answer by

> calculation, or can find it algebraically.

Ultimate hint:

> Line 4 last 2 words.

Comment: But if someone posts the correct answer then Google will be able to find it, thus invalidating it?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky, there are many things with no match in Google and posting the answer won't change this.

Comment: that feels like another hint.

Comment: @Dmitry :), yes!

Comment: Clarification, me = answer to this question. Line 4 answer = another famous answer.

Comment: @Tom Could it be the chemical structure of compounds/elements?

Comment: @ManojKumar, the answer should be known at primary school, no scientific knowledge is needed.

Comment: Okay the 4th hint is not about the "All" tab in Google Search!?

Comment: @Manoj, line 4 isn't about the "All" tab, it's mostly mathematical.

Comment: Is line 2 something you might rot13(qevax juvyr tencuvpf cebtenzzvat)

Comment: @Mohirl, yes to first word. I don't think or see why, I could be wrong, it's the last two words. Researching, I don't think the last two words are the right one(s).

Comment: @Tom I actually thought the same as Mohirl. There is a *very* obvious word which is related to a lemon-lime drink, fairies and what Mohirl mentioned. Are you saying it's not that?

Comment: @hexomino - Ah, shows how much I know about the tech Mohirl mentioned. I thought he was referring to MD (8,3). Indeed the very obvious one is relevant to the clue, but not to the answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay so I think the answer is

> -7

Google cannot find me,

> The minus symbol is Google's way of excluding certain terms so googling -7 on its own does not give anything.

reflected I'm lemon and lime,

> This could be a reference to +7 or "7up" which is a lemon and lime drink

googling 'me' is when you fall,

> ' is interpreted as feet so googling '-7' gives "foot-7 feet" which is -6 feet or "6 feet under", the traditional depth of a coffin in the ground.

me and meme will answer all.

> -7 + (-7)(-7) = -7 + 49 = 42

Comment: This seems right to me... Wow!

Answer (score 9):

Is the answer

> *

Googling it returns

> Your search - * - did not match any documents.

me and meme will answer all.

> * and ** are wildcards, which could answer all searches.

Can't make the middle two lines fit though

> Googling '*' returns answers related to wildcards, but not sure who that's relevant. And no idea what the lemon and lime reference is (

Comment: Works for line 1. I don't think this applies maths (calculation or algebra) in line 4. Some correct method though!

Answer (score 4):

My guess, the answer is:

> **...**

Google cannot find me:

> The search results are empty 
>  
>  
>  [image: No results]

reflected I'm lemon and lime,

> It can be reflected to certain angle and also placed vertically as per the hint.
>   [image: Reflected]

googling 'me' is when you fall,

> It's another name for falling short. So we use it as a filler when we fall short of values during a series of sum, sub etc. and thus reducing the distance as per the hint
>  1+2+3+...+n
>  [image: Falling short]

me and meme will answer all.

> I feel that the **AND** is for the product(*) and can be used as a wild character for all searches.

Comment: Super answer, though there is a different definite one. And in maths is usually another operator.

Comment: Oh Manoj, a little late apology from me. I did a search for and and see that your interpretation is also correct (say in probability), but I had in mind even more basic maths. This is a useful answer.

Comment: I do not know what is there to apologize for :D But I am not good at Math :(

Answer (score 4):

**Partial**
(posting as a second answer as it's unrelated to the original)

Based on the last line and the most recent hint, it seems like the answer should be:

> 14. Or possibly, "What is six times nine?" from the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.

but I'm struggling to fit that into most of the puzzle

Google cannot find me

> If you google the Ultimate Question of "What is six times nine?" you won't get the answer of 42. Or if you google 14, you won't get just 14 answers. Both of those seem a stretch though

reflected I'm lemon and lime,

> Presumably a reference to a well known lemon and lime drink, either 7up or Sprite.

From the Line 2 hint

> a fairy's competitor would seem to indicate sprite. Not sure how you reflect that vertically though.

googling 'me' is when you fall,

No idea

me and meme will answer all.

> 14 and 14 doubled gives 42, the answer to life, the universe, and everything

Ultimate hint:

> Line **4** last **2** words is pretty much spelling out 42, while also pointing out that it's the answer to all.

Comment: Wouldn't "A fairy's competitor" imply that it's is a competitor to sprite, and hence 7up? I'm just trying to find a way to reflect 14 in such a way that "upwards" it is 7.

Comment: @MichaelMoschella, you are right.

Comment: 14 and 14 doubled is 56... ???

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath (14)+(14*2), not (14+14)*2, which checks out for "me and meme"

Comment: @MichaelMoschella -- Oh, I see.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> 'meme....meme'. In other words 'me' repeated many times until Google can no longer find it (returns 0 hits). Posting the answer here, does not invalidate the puzzle. Even if Google finds this post, we can always construct another such word (from 'me') that Google will not be able to find. 'lemon' and 'lime' both contain the word 'me'.

Comment: me is the answer. If don't know it, let it be x.